# How to remove Jquery Validation on clicked on a button

Tags: jquery

I have  got a form which i am validating using jquery Validator plugin .

Everything is working fine , except this scenario .

Initaiily Without filling form , click on the Submit button (The validation messages gets populated)

Now click on the Edit button , some default values gets added to the form fields

My question is once i click on the edit button , how can i remove the Validation part ??

```
$(function() {
    $('#mangementform').validate({
        rules: {
             empid: {
        required: true,
         minlength: 3,
        maxlength: 25,
        digits: true,
          label_exist:true
    },
             empname: {
        required: true,
          minlength: 3,
        maxlength: 25,
        lettersonly:true
     },
        },
        messages: {
            empid: {
                required: "id  required "
            },
            empname: {
                required: "emp name  required ",
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(event, validator) {
            submitMangementForm();
            return false;
        }
    });
});

function submitMangementForm()
{
     $("#empid").val('');
    $("#empname").val('');
    alert('ajax call to submit to Database');
}

$(document).on('click', '.editbtn', function (e) {
    $("#empid").val('123');
    $("#empname").val('test');

});
```

I want to diable the validation only for edit and not for submit .

Could you please help me , in how to resolve that ??

http://jsfiddle.net/5RrGa/1413/

Comment: Are you trying to skip validation completely if edit button is pressed ?

Comment: yes , i am skipping validation if edit button is pressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the clarification in comments. You can try to add [formnovalidate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference#link-skipping-validation-on-submit) attribute on your submit button.

Give an id to button which is causing submit.

```
<button id="submitbutton" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Submit</button>
```

and then inside edit button click event handler, add formnovalidate:

```
$(document).on('click', '.editbtn', function (e) {
    $("#empid").val('123');
    $("#empname").val('test');
    // To Reset the previous error messages
     $("#mangementform").validate().resetForm();
    $('#submitbutton').attr('formnovalidate','');

});
```

Updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5RrGa/1415/).

Comment: I tested your fiddle , initially i clicked on the Submit , displayed validation messages , then i clicked on the edit  still i see the validation messages .

Comment: Check updated answer. You can revalidate and reset form. $("#mangementform").validate().resetForm(); http://jsfiddle.net/5RrGa/1419/